# dropdownlist get value from database using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

below i mentioned our code for dropdownlist value get from database but i got error. error means in angular code not call angular http method  url everthing so dropdown showing empty.

AngularJS

```
 $scope.product = function (e) {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/Prescription/GeneratePrescriptions"
        }).
          then(function (response) {
              $scope.formulationlist = response.data;
          }, function () {
              alert("Error Occur");
          })
    }

Controller

 public ActionResult GeneratePrescriptions()
    {
        FDAGeneric_Bind();
        FDAFormulation_Bind();
        TestFDAFormulation_Bind();
        return View();
    }

 public JsonResult TestFDAFormulation_Bind()
        {
            DataSet ds = dFDA.Get_FDAFormulation();
            List<SelectListItem> Formulationlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Formulationlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["Formulation"].ToString(), Value = dr["FormulationID"].ToString() });
            }
            //ViewBag.MasterFormulationID = Formulationlist;
            return Json(Formulationlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
View

 <td>
                                    <select ng-model="r.formulationid" ng-change="" ng-options=" p.formulationid as p.formulation for p in formulationlist" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Select Product</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
```

Comment: `url: "/Prescription/TestFDAFormulation_Bind"` put your complete url

Comment: url: "/Prescription/GeneratePrescriptions"